# How to sum a column based on specific year?

Tags: r

Suppose I have following time-series data frame in R.

```
Date           Var1
1/1/2010        7
1/2/2010        154
1/3/2010        125
1/4/2010        87
1/5/2010        57
1/6/2010        12
....
....
7/24/2015       5
```

If I want Sum(Var1) on **year 2010 only**, how to do it in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `substr` to get the 'year' part from 'Date' column, use that in `subset` to extract the rows that have '2010' as year, select the 'Var1' column, and get the `sum`

```
 sum(subset(df1, substr(Date,5,8)==2010, select=Var1))
```

Or a `dplyr/lubridate` option would be using `filter` and `summarise` to get similar result.

```
 library(lubridate)
 library(dplyr)
 df1 %>% 
     filter(Date=year(mdy(Date))==2010) %>%
     summarise(Var1= sum(Var1))
```

Comment: Thank you for fast response, I have tried two methods, both works. ~